# Apache Ignite Remove all in transaction mode causing node failure

Tags: java, transactions, ignite, in-memory-database

I want to delete around 30L(30,00,000) data records from my cache and I've used

```
igniteCache.removeAll(listOfKeys)
```

Here I'm fetching the keys and passing to removeAll method of ignite and is working fine. But to to maintain consistency and avoid partial deletion I've decided to use transactions over my operations. But the problem is that : it is taking much time to remove and mainly my ignite server node is stopped.

```
        IgniteTransactions transactions = IgniteConfig.getIgnite().transactions();
        tx = transactions.txStart();
        IgniteCache<String, myCache> igniteCache = 
IgniteConfig.getIgniteCache();
FieldsQueryCursor<List<?>> deletedKeys = igniteCache.query("select id from  
mytable where timeId=xxxx");

Set<String> listOfKeys = new HashSet<>();
List<List<?>> allData = deletedKeys.getAll();

for (List keys : allData) {                  
listOfKeys.add(String.valueOf(keys.get(0)));
}

igniteCache.removeAll(listOfKeys);
tx.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

The default concurrency level is TransactionConcurrency.PESSIMISTIC, so on

```
  igniteCache.removeAll(listOfKeys);
```

call Ignite will lock all these keys first and then remove on tx commit.

I think in your case you need to remove all these keys in SQL if you need to do this transactionally, you can use transactional SQL introduced in 2.7 version:
https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/transactions

Also, you can change transaction concurrency to OPTIMISTIC, this will significantly reduce the time for the transaction.

Comment: I,ve tried transaction concurrency to OPTIMISTIC but didn't find much difference in time. Okay i will also SQL transactions. Thanks for valuable reply.